# Debugger always stops on jQuery 1.7.2 in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: jquery, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chrome Dev Tools to debug styles and scripts.

When I activate the tools panel, on every site I browse (even here on SO) it always stops on a portion of a file I don't have in any project: `jquery-1.7.2.min.js`.
If I `continue` it continues to stop for about ten breakpoints, the I can debug MY code.

Where do this file come from? I searched in Chrome's settings, but I found nothing I can relate to this... How can I avoid this behaviour?

This makes my Dev Tools quite unusable, especially when I want only to debug styles.

Comment: Which chrome version are you using? No update error? Maybe just try reinstalling chrome

Comment: I'm using version 31.0.1650.57 m. No update error (it's up to date). I'll give it a try with re-install. Thx.

Comment: I have reinstalled and disabled some plug-in, and now it's ok. But, how can I detect which plug-in have loaded a file that I see in the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have some chrome plugin that are using these javascript file.If you want that it should not break on unwanted break point then you can click

> Pass on uncaught exception from chrome tool bar.

Comment: Thank you. I think this was the problem. Removed plungins and now it's ok.